# Jenkins: How to change shell in Scripted Pipeline?

Tags: shell, jenkins

Print default shell with below script.

```
node {
    stage('Clean'){
        echo "${SHELL}"
...
}
```

From log, it's /usr/local/bin/tcsh.

```
[Pipeline] echo  
/usr/local/bin/tcsh
```

How to change it to another shell, like /bin/csh?

Answer (score 1):

Tried below code, echo still prints "/usr/local/bin/tcsh", but suddenly /bin/csh environment variable is available.

```
stage('Clean'){
        sh '''#!/bin/csh
                echo "Clean old coverage data"
                echo "${SHELL}"
        '''
}
```